# Tout cela vs. tous ceux-là

Tags: choix-de-mot

> L'analphabétisme, la pauvreté, les coutumes, la religion, tous ceux-là tournent ensembles dans un cercle vicieux.

Or should it be "tout cela" instead?

Comment: **Ensemble** being here an adverb is invariable so shouldn't have this extra **s**.

Comment: Is that a sentence you wrote or did you read it somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

No, it would require grammar and meaning change.

*tous ceux-là*=*all of them*, insists on the absence of exception, all of them are roaming into a vicious circle.

*tout cela*=*all of this*, consider the thing as a whole. The sentence would also require to be rewritten as *tout cela tourne dans un cercle vicieux*=*all of this is roaming into a vicious circle*.

Comment: Don't you mean “Yes, and it would require …”? The sentence as it is doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The connotations of "roaming into" are not proper; it's only a question of "tourner" which is, at that figurative; it is no more than "run around". Moreover, this phrase, initially from the domain of logic, is not used very idiomatically with "tourner", even in a figurative way ("tourner dans un cercle vicieux" is on the decline in French); the popular "tourner en rond" is not to be taken as a template.

Answer (score 3):

“Tous ceux-là” looks strange in this sentence. The pronoun “*ceux*” designates a subset of its antecedent. The sentence doesn't have a suitable antecedent for *ceux* (“*l'analphabétisme, la pauvreté, les coutumes, la religion*” is the subset, not the antecedent). Furthermore using ”*ceux-là*“ tends to imply that this is not the only subset: there should be at least one other subset designated by “*ceux-ci*”. It can work in the proper context, but it's a bit of a stretch.

> Les civilisations sont confrontées à de nombreux problèmes. Certains, comme la guerre, peuvent être résolus isolément. Mais d'autres sont plus pernicieux. L'analphabétisme, la pauvreté, les coutumes, la religion, tous ceux-là tournent ensemble dans un cercle vicieux.

This is ok grammatically. There is an antecedent “*problèmes*”, then a discussion of at least one such problem (“*la guerre*”), and then a discussion of another set of problems which can be referred to with “*ceux-là*”. However I don't think my made-up context makes much sense.

On the other hand, with “*tout cela*” instead of “*tous ceux-là*”, the sentence makes sense. There is a set of problems, and since the sentence is about them interacting, they are considered as a whole, using a singular pronoun. The use of *ceci* or *cela* is largely indifferent.

> L'analphabétisme, la pauvreté, les coutumes, la religion, tout cela tourne ensemble dans un cercle vicieux.